# How to prevent developers to push on a particular branch?

Tags: git

We've recently changed `feature` name from `foo` to `bar`. This is a good opportunity to create a new branch at the latest `master` state from which the work will go on.

The previous branch needs to be kept for its history and I cannot be deleted yet.

Therefore I would like to find a mechanism that prevent confused developers to push changes on the wrong branch. My trick is:

```
$ git checkout feature/foo
$ git commit --allow-empty -m "WARNING: DO NOT COMMIT on this branch"
$ git push
```

Unfortunately I would prefer a solution like

```
$ git branch --lock feature/foo -m "Use feature/bar instead"
$ git push
```

What other option could I use?

Note: I can also rename the current branch `git branch -m feature/foo feature/bar`, but this is off topic.

Comment: `The previous branch needs to be kept for its history and I cannot be deleted yet.` You could delete the branch, and create a tag of the same name.

Comment: Using a tag is a pretty decent trick.  Note, though, that old versions of git (up to about 1.8.something) allow pushes to fast-forward tags, i.e., treat them exactly the same as branches.  (Though you cannot check them out like branches, so you gain a fair bit of safety there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like something you would want to use git hooks for. The [pre-push hook](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/githooks.txt#L181) can quite easily specify such a limitation.

In the `.git/hooks` folder, create a script called `pre-push`. The contents should be a Bash script that returns 1 in case you want to prevent the push. My first idea of it is along these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
locked_branch='feature/foo'
push_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

if [ "$locked_branch" = "$push_branch" ]
then
    echo "Do not push this branch! Use feature/bar instead"
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

EDIT:

The above is of course given the constraint that there's no proper server that would run hooks. In the presence of a server however, it should be the `update` script on the server-side enforcing this, the first parameter of which is the branch being updated. So it would work with a check like

```
if [ "$locked_branch" = "$1" ]
```

instead of having a `push_branch` variable, based on the first script posted.

Comment: The problem with using pre-push hooks is that you must convince every user to install such a hook.  This *is* better than convincing every user to remember, for a long time, not to push to the named branch, but not nearly as good as preventing accidents by having the server do it, so that users cannot screw it up...

Comment: @torek A server-side update hook should be better, and I'm editing that info in, but the constraint in this question is that the repos are just lying around on a fie system, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of thing that pre-receive and update hooks are designed for.

Establishing such a hook on the server requires access to the server.  You do not mention whether this is your own server, or some "git as a service" (GaaS?) provider.  Providers always have their own private methods of establishing hooks since, for security reasons, they do not give you full access to the server.

If it is your own private server, create a hook, in whatever language you like.  Check whether an incoming reference change (in `pre-receive`) or the requested reference change (in `update`) is for the branch `feature/foo`.  If so, print an error message for the user: this error will be copied to their machine, prefixed with `remote:`.

```
#! /bin/sh
status=0
while read oldsha newsha refname; do
    case $refname in
    refs/heads/feature/foo)
        echo "branch feature/foo is deprecated, use feature/bar" 1>&2
        status=1
        ;;
    esac
done
exit $status
```

(an example `pre-receive` hook).

Note that using a pre-receive hook, rejection will reject the *entire* push, i.e., if I were attempting to push both `feature/foo` and `personal/blah`, I would see:

```
remote: branch feature/foo is deprecated, use feature/bar
```

and my push would fail, with `personal/blah` not being updated either.

Using an `update` hook, my push would half-fail and half-succeed: I would see the same error message and `feature/foo` would not get pushed, but `personal/blah` would.

Comment: Damned it, I would have mentioned this: we don't use any server but bare repositories somewhere on the network. (It will take ages to convince our management that a Git server may be useful for something)

Comment: "bare repositories somewhere on the network" = "somewhere" is your server!  (Though if it's just presented as a file system or network drive, you are a bit stuck—pushes there will not invoke hooks.)